# Titanium - Textarea within a ScrollView

Tags: javascript, android, textarea, scrollview, titanium-mobile

I am trying to create a textarea box within a scrollview. The problem is that it works in iOS, but in Android, when typing multiple lines within the textarea, I cannot scroll up and down to view what I have typed. I know in native Android that you can provide a maximum number of lines and the scrollbars to allow in the view XML file that allows a scrollable textarea within a scrollview, but is there a way to do something similar or a different way of doing this for Titanium?

Here is the code which I am using:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'Test',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
});

var view = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    right: 10,
});

var ta = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
    top: 5,
    left: 5,
    right: 5,
    height: 400,
    backgroundColor: '#AA8BC9'
});

var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    top: 800,
    left: 10,
    right: 10,
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    backgroundColor: 'FF00CC',
    text: 'OK'
});

view.add(ta);
view.add(btn);
win.add(view);
win.open();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kibria, This is the problem in old titanium sdk. I also facing this problem with tableview and scrollview in android. I hope this problem can resolve in new titanium sdk.

The alternative solution is you need to set scrollview layout to vertical. and your TextArea height set to auto and then add your button. In this way your scrollview and textarea works perfect for you.